# OOP-Design for validating user input

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

Currently, I try to design some things with OO principles in mind. So let's say, before processing user input, I need to validate it. According to OO, a separate Validator class would be the correct way. This would look as follows:

```
    public class Validator{
      public void validate(String input) throws ValidationException{
        if (input.equals("")) throw new ValidationException("Input was empty");
      }
    }
```

Then, my processing class, which got the validator object before via dependency injection would call `validator.validate(input)`

A good point about this design is, that

1. My processing class can get a mock for the validator via DI which makes testing easier
2. The Validator class can be tested independently

However, my doubts are in the design of the Validator. According to OO, it misses some kind of state. With this design, it is as util class and the validate method could be `static`. And I read a lot of times that (static) Util classes are bad OO design. So, how can this be done with more OO while keeping the two advantages I mentioned?

PS.: Maybe, OO is simply a bad solution for this kind of problem. However, I would like to see how the OO solution would look like and form my own opinion.

Comment: I believe it's better to write all validation errors to collection and return it. Then you can process errors as you wish(exception, proper html page, json responce etc). Assume user have to fill some form with 10 fields - your design will throw an exception on the first one and do not tell anything about 9 other. So your validator purpose only to check data and return result, and other class will write a response.

Comment: You're right, I haven't thought about this before.

Answer (score 1):

The validator in your example doesn't have a state (and doesn't need any), but another validator could require one (say with a format):

Example:

```
public class RegExValidator {
    private Pattern pattern;

    public RegExValidator(String re) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    }

    public void validate(String input) throws ValidationException {
        if (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
            throw new ValidationException("Invalid syntax [" + input + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Concentrating on the OOP aspect of your question (rather than the question if an Exception is the correct way to handle your validation):

Why have a single validator?

```
interface Validator<T> {
    void validate(T toValidate) throws ValidationException;
}
```

would enable you to write classes that can validate any class `T` and be very testable. Your validator would look like this:

```
class EmptyStringValidator implements Validator<String> {
    public void validate(String toValidate) {
        if(toValidate == null || toValidate.isEmpty()) throw new ValidationException("empty!!!");
    }
}
```

and you could test it very easily.
In fact, if you're using Java 8, this would be a functional interface, so a single utility class could host several validators:

```
class ValidationUtil {
    public static void emptyString(String val) // same code as above
}
```

and `ValidationUtil::emptyString` would implement `Validator<String>`.
You would combine several validators with a composite pattern.

You could also have a validator with a state if that's what you need...

```
class ListIsSortedValidator implements Validator<Integer> {
    private int lastInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public void validate(Integer val) throw ValidationException {
        if (val < lastInt) throw new ValidationException("not sorted");
        lastInt = val;
    }
}
```

That you could use to for instance validate a list:

```
List<Integer> list = createList();
Validator<Integer> validator = new ListIsSortedValidator();
list.forEach(validator::validate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circumstances of course, but I think your instinct is correct. This design could be more Object-Oriented.

It is not just that `Validator` has no state, which is a purely mechanical indicator that it is likely not a correct abstraction, but the name itself tells us something. Usually `Validator` (or even `EmptyStringValidator`) is not part of the problem domain. It is always a bad sign when you have to create something purely technical (although sometimes it is the less of two evils).

I assume you are not writing a web-framework, you are trying to write an application that has some domain. For example it has user registration. Then, `RegistrationForm` is part of the problem domain. Users *know* about the "registration form", you can talk about it and they will know what you mean.

In this case, an Object-Oriented solution for validation would be that this object is responsible for the validation of itself during the "submitting" of itself.

```java
public final class RegistrationForm extends Form {
    ...
    @Override
    public void submit() {
        // Do validation here
        // Set input fields to error if there are problems
        // If everything ok do logic
    }
}
```

I know this is not the solution normally seen or even supported by web-frameworks. But it *is* how an Object-Oriented solution would look like.

The two important points to always keep in mind are:

1. Don't "get" data from objects, ask them to do something instead. This is as applicable to UI code as anything else.
2. OO makes sense when the objects focus on meaningful things, i.e. the problem domain. Avoid over-representing technical (unimportant) objects, like `Validator` (if that's not your application's domain).